# Как корректно записать данную конструкцию из for?

Tags: python

Есть такая констуркция:

```
equation = "32 * {} + 33 * {} + 34 * {} + 35 * {} + 36 * {} + 37 * {} + 38 * {} + 39 * {} + 40 * {} + 41 * {}"

for i in range(100):
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            for g in range(100):
                ...
                if i + x + y + g + h + f + s + a + q + w <= 98:
                    eq = equation.format(w, q, a, s, f, h, g, y, x, i)
                    res = eval(eq)
                    if res == 8932:
                        print(f'{eq} = {res}')
```

Хотелось бы узнать как можно записать такую конструкцию куда проще с возможностью масшабирования.

Comment: человек ниже всё прекрасно понял, 4 вложенных цикла for по умолчанию решение плохое и не эффективное

Comment: Задача-то в чём - комбинации с данной суммой сгенерировать? Оценку текстового выражения для этого использовать - хм...

Comment: Я совершенно не просил оптимизировать алгоритм и делать его "эффективнее", я просил записать эту конструкцию проще с возможностью масштабирования. Я повторю что я совершенно не просил никого лезть с оптимизацией и оценкой за сколько миллионов лет этот алгоритм всё переберёт, я просто попросил упростить конструкцию и точка.

Comment: Человек который мне ответил прекрасно понял задачу и выполнил её без отсебятины. А вы товарищи и дальше сидите и нойте о неоптимизированности решения и то как некоторым непонятно

Comment: Из-за условия на сумму переменных (*<= 98*) решений у системы нет. Максимум линейной комбинации *98 * 41 = 4018 < 8932*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так, например. Только при таких вводных окончания процесса ждать можно до конца Вселенной ))

```py
from itertools import product
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

n = 10
equation = ' + '.join(f"{32 + i} * {{}}" for i in range(n))
for numbers in tqdm(product(range(100), repeat=n), total=100**n):
    if sum(numbers) <= 98:
        eq = equation.format(*numbers)
        res = eval(eq)
        if res == 8932:
            print(f'{eq} = {res}')
```

Update: Потерял сначала условие на сумму, добавил.

Comment: У `product` есть аргумент `repeat`

Comment: Потеряно условие на сумму переменных.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy точно, потерял )

Comment: Вы только не добавляйте его обратно. Решений не будет. Зря я вообще это сказал.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну не будет и не будет. Человек спросил как проще эту всю конструкцию записать, я показал )